# User Account Mismatch

Tags: sql-server, permissions

My disk crashed so I reinstalled SQL Server to a new drive and restored my databases from my backup drive.  However, when I attempt to install Diagram support, I get this message:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist....

This issue is admirably answered [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186179/cannot-execute-as-the-database-principal-because-the-principal-does-not-exist) but the reply doesn't seem to apply in my case since running the first query in the "Solution" section returns no records so I have nothing to fix, yet I get that error message.

Here are my results from the queries suggested in that reply:
[image: Database Principals]
[image: Server Principals]

Please inform me how to resolve this matter.

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT [name], SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid), owner_sid FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = '<db name>'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `owner` of your `database` on the old `server` was some `Windows account` that does not exists as `login` on the new server (if it existed, its login `sid` would match user `sid` as it's Windows account, so it's Windows `sid`).

To fix it you can make `sa` the `owner` of your database:

```
alter authorization on database::YourDBName to sa
```

Or any other `login` (I just don't see other logins on your picture that are not certificate logins)